# Stuck with implementing custom control structure

Tags: scala

My assignment is to write a custom `repeat` control structure that can be used like this:

```
var i = 0
repeat {
    i = i + 1
}(i > 5)
```

I currently have the following code for that:

```
def repeat(f: => Unit): ((=> Boolean) => Unit) = {
    (x) => {
        while (x) f
    }
}
```

When running this, it seems f (`i = i + 1`) is never executed.

I have to be honest, I'm not entirely sure what the current type of `x` is. It's clearly not correct, but I don't have enough knowledge to know where to go from here.

I used to have this:

```
def repeat(f: => Unit): ((=> Boolean) => Void) = {
    (x: (=> Boolean)) => {
        while (x) f
    }
}
```

Although this is apparently incorrect Scala, I think it demonstrates my intent better.

I'm sorry if my question is a bit broad/demonstrates effortlessness, but the concept of by-name parameters is very new to me and not explained in my book *(Programming in Scala)* beyond the basics.

Comment: Why don't you encompass all logic inside your function (possibly parameterized with more closures)? Currently what you're returning back is closure, which then gets applied in the outer scope.

Comment: hint: `while (i > 5) i += 1` is never true when `i` is initialized with 0...

Comment: @sschaef I have no idea how I missed that. Still, I'd like to know more about the types here.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I can't change that, this is the assignment I was given.

Comment: @Overv so assignment has required signature [and code] which you can't change?

Comment: @om-nom-nom The given requirement is that it can be used in the way shown in the first snippet. If you meant something else, I misunderstood and I apologize.

Comment: @Overv well, both I and [Rex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15475821/298389) proposed the code which is compliant with very first snippet. It is actually *uncurried* (in some sense) version of what you're trying to write right now.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Ah, I understand now. That does make it much easier.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Nevermind, those snippets do not seem to compatible. The compiler will complain that `i > 5` is a Boolean and not a function. If I take Rex' code, it seems like I would definitely have to change the calling code.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Nevermind, I've altered my code to only make use of the multiple parameter blocks tip: http://pastebin.com/gETf4w3K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also be aware that Scala supports *multiple parameter lists*.  So you could

```
def compare(a: Int, b: Int)(p: (Int,Int) => Boolean) = p(a,b)
```

and then write

```
compare(5,2)(_ > _)
```

This type of strategy will simplify your logic.

Also, you have your comparison backwards.  `i` starts out at `0` and your loop condition is `i > 5`, which it is not.

A few extra notes: `=> X` means "compute an X each time one is needed", so `((=> Boolean) => Unit)` takes something that will compute a `Boolean` as needed (and `i > 5` can do that, if the check is performed each time, which it will be).  `(=> Boolean) => Unit` means a function that takes as input something that produces `Boolean`s and gives no output.  (Well, strictly speaking, `Unit` type is an output, namely `()`, which is done for consistency.  But it serves the same role as `void`.)

Comment: Thanks, the multiple parameter blocks absolutely makes this easier. This is my solution: http://pastebin.com/gETf4w3K

Comment: If you're not allowed to do it that way, I added a few notes to help you understand what the curried type signatures mean.

Comment: More accurately described as multiple parameter _lists_.

Comment: @RandallSchulz - Whoops, thanks.  Answered this one too early  in the morning.